# Get words start with @ like facebook mentions by regex and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

first of all  i know there is many topics talks about this case but not like i want 
i want to get the words like Facebook do in mentions names in comments
here is my conditions

1- i want all words start with @ char

2- i want all lonely @ char

3- i don't want any words that contain '@' like any@hotmail.com

EX: "@ this d@y @hmed @nd May@ went to play @ g@arden"

the result i want is

{"@" , "@hmed" ,"@nd" , "@"}

**please notice the second condition i want**
thanks

Comment: This is not a question, just a request for "do my work"

Comment: People are likely to help you, but unlikely to do the entire thing for you. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: i am trying to make an auto complete extender and am using javascript, Ajax, and web service i tried to use this expression /(\W)@[\w]*/gi.exec(MyString) but it dosen't work perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **regex** should be `/(?:^|\s)(@[^@\s]*)(?=\s|$)/g`

[ *test: http://ideone.com/1LK80* ]

Comment: I believe not every question deserve an answer...

Comment: Thanks a lot that is work and my code is ......... var MyWords = MyString.match(/(?:^|\s)(@[^@\s]*)(?=\s|$)/g);